# Splitting strings in tuples within a pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization

I have a pandas dataframe where a column contains tuples:

```
p = pd.DataFrame({"sentence" : [("A.Hi",   "B.My",   "C.Friend"), \
                                ("AA.How", "BB.Are", "CC.You")]})
```

I'd like to split each string in the tuple on a punctuation `.`, take the second part of the split/string and see how many match list of strings:

```
p["tmp"] = p["sentence"].apply(lambda x: [i.split(".")[1] for i in x])
p["tmp"].apply(lambda x: [True if len(set(x).intersection(set(["Hi", "My"])))>0 else False])
```

This works as intended, but my dataframe has more than 100k rows - and `apply` doesn't seem very efficient at these sizes. Is there a way to optize/vectorize the above code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use nested list and set comprehension and for test convert sets to `bool`s - empty `set` return `False`:

```
s = set(["Hi", "My"])
p["tmp"] = [bool(set(i.split(".")[1] for i in x).intersection(s)) for x in p["sentence"]]

print (p)
                   sentence    tmp
0    (A.Hi, B.My, C.Friend)   True
1  (AA.How, BB.Are, CC.You)  False
```

EDIT:

If there are only 1 or 2 length values after split, you can select last value by indexing `[-1]`:

```
p = pd.DataFrame({"sentence" : [("A.Hi",   "B.My",   "C.Friend"), \
                                ("AA.How", "BB.Are", "You")]})

print (p)
                 sentence
0  (A.Hi, B.My, C.Friend)
1   (AA.How, BB.Are, You)

s = set(["Hi", "My"])

p["tmp"] = [bool(set(i.split(".")[-1] for i in x).intersection(s)) for x in p["sentence"]]
print (p)
                 sentence    tmp
0  (A.Hi, B.My, C.Friend)   True
1   (AA.How, BB.Are, You)  False
```

Comment: Is it possible to only grab the second element if it exists, otherwise grap the first (i.e., `[1]` if exists, otherwise `[0]`?)

Comment: @N08 - I think yes, but need some time.

Comment: A quick work-around is to reverse the order of the string, get the `[0]`-element after splitting, then revert back

Comment: or using if-else with test length of splitted values, I have no idea what solution is better/faster.